# In a graphical model of C dependant on both A and B, is it possible to get the joint distribution of C and B?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, joint-distribution, graphical-model

Imagine we have a graphical model of random variable C that is dependent both on A and B. This is like a node C which has two incoming arrows. One from node A and the other from B.

An example is me getting Sinus dependent on either me being allergic or me having flu. So sinus is the node C. Allergic is the node A and flu being the node B.

I know that the joint probability of all these three random variables is P(A,B,C) which is P(C|A,B)*P(A)*P(B).

How do we get the joint distribution of C and B for example? How do we derive the P(C,B)?

In other words does it make sense at all for me to expect the joint distribution to exist? If no why not?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It exists as long as the joint for all variables exist, and you can calculate it as follows:

$$P(B,C)=\sum_{a\in\mathcal{A}}P(A,B,C)=P(B) \sum_{a\in\mathcal{A}} P(C|A,B)P(A)$$

Comment: thanks for this. Also you said as long as joint for all variables exist. Given the scenario can the joint of all variables not exist too? Is there a situation you can think of where the join doesn't exist? I thought in the given graphical model it always exists

Comment: yes, it exists. it was a general statement not limited to bayesian networks.

Comment: thanks it is clear now